# how to translate the name of pages in liferay 6

Tags: liferay-6

I want to translate the name of page present in liferay. The first page name is welcome provided by liferay. How we can translate this name to a specific language.

Thanks

asif aftab

Answer (score 1):

6.1 or 6.2 ?

as for 6.2 you can localize friendly urls: [see this blog entry](http://www.liferay.com/de/web/sergio.gonzalez/blog/-/blogs/localize-layout-friendly-urls)

for 6.1 it is not possible out of the box, ( [see this](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/18371671) there is a proof of concept provided, maybe you can find a workarround.
Or you can create multiple pages and for each one create a friendly url in the requiered language( i don't think this is a good way :))

Answer (score 0):

Well, you CAN translate the **name** of your pages even in version 6.1 (though translation of friendlyURLs is not supported before 6.2 version). Here is how you can do it: http://javarushi.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/localize-names-titles-of-liferay-pages.html.

I have used this feature myself. It works w/o any issues.